# GCC - Struct defining members in specific offsets

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Is there a way in gcc, where I could define a struct with a specific member in a specific offset?

I want to define a struct in the following way:

```
struct {
.offset(0xDC) //or something equivalent
   int bar;
} foo;
```

and then the following statement:

```
int a = foo.bar
```

will be identical to the statement:

```
int a = *(int*)((char*)&foo + 0xDC);
```

* UPDATE ***

Some background:
I want to access members in an exported struct which I have no proper definition, it has many members - which I care about only a handful of them, and their offset (the struct original definition) is a bit different on each target platform (I need to compile my code for a few different platforms)

I have considered the padding option mentioned on the comments here, but it requires me to do some annoying calculations each time I want to add a member.
for example:

```
strcut {
.offset(0xDC)
    int bar;
.offset(0xF4)
    int moo;
}foo;
```

is simpler then:

```
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) struct {
   char pad1[0xD8];
   int bar;
   char pad2[0x18];
   int moo;
}foo;
```

and that without taking into consideration the fact the sizeof(int) can change from platform to platform

Comment: Did you mean [bit-fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field#Examples) ?

Comment: I think that no, and if you really want constant offsets, I'll do that with cast and pointers, like e.g. `*((int*)(((char*)p)+0xd8))` which you could hide in a macro.

Answer (score 10):

You should have a look at [`__attribute__ ((__packed__))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

In your case you would write:

```
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
   char unused[0xDC];
   int bar;
} foo;
```

If you could explain what you're trying to do there may be other, possibly more elegant, solutions.

Comment: I forgot to mention the packed attribute although I hinted at it +1

Comment: I m trying to write a code that runs on a few different platforms. I want to access a structure that is exported by a different module, not written by myself, and to which I have no headers. On each platform, the members I want to access are on different offsets, I want that offset to be a macro defined by the build system for each platform... Your solution I what I am currently using, but I wanted to know if there is anything clearer

Comment: @t_z Actually I think this is the only way to do it unless you save this into a buffer and do the offsets from there which will get you the same result albeit more complicated looking.

Comment: @t_z I don't think that using a structure is the best choice; I would make a function (or more) to parse that structure depending on platform. This way I could avoid doing some compilation tricks, which in my opinion increases complexity of the build system.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using padding and union as proposed in other answers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OFF_STRUCT(name, members) union { members } name

#define OFF_MEMB(offset, member)                 \
        struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {    \
                char pad[offset];                \
                member;                          \
        }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        OFF_STRUCT(foo,
                OFF_MEMB(0xD8, int bar);
                OFF_MEMB(0x18, double moo);
                OFF_MEMB(0x1, int bee);
        );

        printf("offset: 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n",
                (void*)&foo.bar - (void*)&foo,
                (void*)&foo.moo - (void*)&foo,
                (void*)&foo.bee - (void*)&foo
        );
}
```

Output:

```
offset: 0xd8 0x18 0x1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always pad it with bytes and make sure that you tell gcc not to align your structs (as this may throw off the offsets). In that case you would need a member like `char pad_bytes[num_pad_bytes];`. Although is there a reason to really do this? You can always calculate the offset of a member of a struct by doing some pointer arithmetic.
Note: you may want to use the `uint8_t` type to pad instead of char as some compilers may actually pad char (which is usually a byte) to the size of a word.

Calculating offset is as simple as

```
size_t offset = (size_t)&((struct_type *)0)->member);
```

All this does is simply return a pointer to where member would be in struct_type if the struct were at 0x00 in memory (which it can never be) but since we use 0 as a base then the offset is simply the reference returned by the & operator.

Comment: "_All this does is simply_" get undefined behaviour. You are dereferencing a null pointer!

Comment: @curiousguy Nope actually, it doesn't actually dereference it because of the & operator. The generic linked list implementation in C uses this exact macro (in the linux kernel as well look for container_of macro). Here's the link for you just in case http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.2/include/linux/stddef.h#L20

Comment: @JesusRamos, in this case you should use the perfectly standard C99/C++98/C++11 macro `offsetof`.

Comment: "_char (which is usually a byte)_" A `char` **by definition** is a byte, so it needs no alignment (alignment = 1).

Comment: "_You can remove your downvote now :)_" I can't. A dereference is a dereference, and UB is UB. `*p` is a dereference of `p`, and **it is illegal if `p` does not point to an object**.

Comment: @curiousguy It is not illegal, the & is an address of operator, you don't actually use the value pointed there or even dereference it at all. Also character is sometimes aligned to a word size (4 bytes or so) which is what I meant so any offset that isn't aligned to a word may be padded with bytes to have such an alignment.

Comment: "_Also character is sometimes aligned to a word size (4 bytes or so)_" Compilers may introduce padding in a struct for any reason. **By definition, `char` has an _alignment requirement_ of 1.** This means that a `char` can lie at any address, by definition. So if compilers are adding padding so that a `char` is aligned, it isn't be to obey **alignment requirement**. Which compilers are doing that, BTW?

Comment: "_It is not illegal, the & is an address of operator, you don't actually use the value pointed_" I think I know what the `&` does. Before you take the address, you have **a dereference**. A dereference is not valid if the dereferenced pointer **does not point to an object**. This is really elementary: in order for `f(g(x))` to be well-defined, `g(x)` has to be well-defined, and `f(y)` has to well-defined (where `y` is the value of the result `g(x)`). There is nothing here even slightly subtle.

Comment: "_The generic linked list implementation in C uses this exact macro (in the linux kernel as well look for container_of macro)._" You cannot take code from linux as a proof that something is well-defined C. **The linux kernel is not even written in C.**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5295/discussion-between-jesus-ramos-and-curiousguy)

Comment: **Moderator Note** _Some comments under this answer were removed because they degraded into noise. Please keep comments constructive, professional and on topic_

Comment: "Here's the link for you just in case" lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.2/include/linux/stddef.h#L20 It is very interesting to note that if there is a builtin macro `__compiler_offsetof`, the `offsetof` macro will not involve a null pointer dereference.

Answer (score 2):

> I have considered the padding option mentioned on the comments here, but it requires me to do some annoying calculations each time I want to add a member.

Regarding annoying calculations, you can just *generate* the declaration of your struct using your preferred scripting language:

```python
struct = { 0xdc : (4, 'int bar'),
           0xf4 : (4, 'int moo') }

def print_struct_decl (name, decl):
        print "struct __attribute__ ((packed)) %s {" % name
        off = 0
        i = 0;
        for o in sorted (decl.keys()):
                print "\tchar pad%d [%d];" % (i, o - off)
                i = i + 1
                off = off + o + decl[o][0]
                print "\t%s;" % decl[o][1]
        print "};"

print_struct_decl ("whatever", struct)
```

Outputs:

```
struct __attribute__ ((packed)) whatever {
    char pad0 [220];
    int bar;
    char pad1 [20];
    int moo;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a class that wraps a pointer:

```
class whateverPtr {
    unsigned char *p;

public:
    whateverPtr(void *p) : p(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(p) { }

    uint32_t getBar() const { return read_uint32(0xdc); }

private:
    uint32_t read_uint32(unsigned int offset) {
        return p[offset] |
            (p[offset + 1] << 8) |
            (p[offset + 2] << 16) |
            (p[offset + 3] << 24);
    }
};
```

This is fully portable and will work as expected on bigendian architectures. Signed integers are a bit trickier as you need to get the encoding right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fits your needs with gcc, but I use this solution all the time and it works great with my VS compiler:

```
#define STR_MERGE_IMPL(a, b) a##b
#define STR_MERGE(a, b) STR_MERGE_IMPL(a, b)
#define MAKE_PAD(size) STR_MERGE(_pad, __COUNTER__)[size]
#define DEFINE_MEMBER_N(type, name, offset) struct {unsigned char MAKE_PAD(offset); type name;}

struct Foo
{
    union {
        DEFINE_MEMBER_N(int, bar, 0x8);
    };
};

Foo foo;
foo.bar++;
```

credits to Can1357